# Error thrown when collection is modified within foreach loop

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I have a small card game I'm making and the foreach loop throws an error on the last iteration in the collection. I assumed it was to do with the memory addressing so added the handTemp list to be iterated through instead. Still throws the same error though, can anybody help? thanks.

```
List<Card> handTemp = new List<Card>();
handTemp = players[0].hand;

foreach (Card c in handTemp)
{
   if (c.strName == crd.strName)
   {
       players[0].hand.Remove(c);
       pile.Add(c);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes indeed. The code is from one of the suggested answers on the page but it still throws the error.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea with the `handTemp` variable is correct, but you have an error in your implementation:

```
List<Card> handTemp = new List<Card>();
handTemp = players[0].hand;
```

This basicaly says 'create a new variable `handTemp`, assign to it a new list and then completely discard that list, instead pointing `handTemp` to `players[0].hand`'. What you probably wanted to do is:

```
List<Card> handTemp = new List<Card>(players[0].hand);
```

Alternatively, as Henk commented below, if you're in the wonderful world of .NET 3.5+, you might use the LINQ method:

```
var handTemp = players[0].hand.ToList();
```

Comment: That is not an error, and also not an answer to question.

Comment: @Maarten Not sure I follow: this fix would make the presented code work without error. One could comment about performance vs a `for` loop, but such comments are hard to make in vacuum (and given those objects represent players' hands in a small card game I don't expect the collections to be significantly large).

Comment: @decPl I've misread a thing in your answer, my apologies. You are correct.

Comment: Maarten, decPL thanks for the input. I think I've got it now. :)

Answer (score 0):

If i have understand your problem clearly here `players[0].hand` and `handTemp` are reference type.

so in `foreach` while you removing item from  `players[0].hand` it refers that you are also removing item from `handTemp`.

**Note: a collection cannot be modified at the same time you are iterating through it.**

to resolve this you can replace, 
`handTemp = players[0].hand;` with `handTemp = players[0].hand.ToList();`

`.ToList()` will create a new `List()` and will not affect `handTemp` to be modified.

Hope this help. correct me if i am wrong.